# Create a SharePoint 2010 list with Custom Template programmatically in WinForms, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to create a SharePoint 2010 List with a Custom Template from WinForms or WPF.

I use the Web reference ../_vti_bin/lists.asmx (called ListsService):

```
ListsService.Lists listWebService = new ListsService.Lists(); 
listWebService.Url = "<na-na-na>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";   
listWebService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 //Call AddList method of Web service to create new list
XmlNode result = listWebService.AddList("TestList", "Test Description", 100);`
```

And in AddList method one should define the templateID, 
however, there are a lot of custom templates on site with the same ID = 100. Because, I guess, it means that this is a "Generic List". So, when the list is created, no template is applied to it.

Please, advise what should I do to get the exact template I need?